# My Sql, query com dois parâmetros diferentes para mesma coluna para trazer dois resultados diferentes

Tags: mysql, query

tenho uma situação que preciso calcular o total de salas com mais de 50 metros, aí depois preciso calcular as que são com mais de 100 metros, e assim suscetivamente. Existe uma forma que posso fazer na mesma query? Preciso que o resultado seja por cidade:

[image: Como tem que aparecer o resultado]

calcular uma por vez é bem tranquilo:

```
select
    CIDADE,
    COUNT(SALA) as totalSalaAte50
from
    EDIFICACOES
where
    AREA_SALA <= 50
GROUP by
    CIDADE;
```

Comment: sim é possível mas tem de colocar a estrutura da tabela na pergunta, e melhor se tiver alguns dados. Ah melhor ainda se conseguir montar um exemplo no http://sqlfiddle.com/ ai é possível te ajudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Sim é possível fazer isso. Note que cada contagem deve ter um critério, que é "SALA < 50", etc.

Para fazer isso, pode user dentro do `COUNT` um `CASE WHEN` para validar a metragem para cada critério que precisa, assim por exemplo:

`COUNT (CASE WHEN SALA < 50 THEN 1 END) AS ATE50`

Isso significa que, "caso a sala seja menor que 50, retorna 1", ou seja, conta 1.

Daí é só seguir o mesmo raciocínio para os demais:

```
SELECT CIDADE,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN SALA < 50 THEN 1 END) AS ATE50,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN SALA BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN 1 END) AS ATE100,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN SALA BETWEEN 100 AND 149 THEN 1 END) AS ATE150
  FROM Edificacoes
 GROUP BY CIDADE;
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/737b24/9